# Running Spring Boot Application with -XX:+UseSerialGC vs -XX:+UseParallelGC

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, garbage-collection

I ran Spring Boot application without any garbage collection command-line option on ubuntu server.

**java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)**

Its taking more RAM memory around >500MB+

When I checked google and SO, got -XX:+UseSerialGC 
With this command-line option, its taking only 200-300MB RAM memory.

Later heard that using -XX:+UseParallelGC best option when compared to -XX:+UseSerialGC

So I used that but its taking around >500MB+ only.

What is the best command-line option to take less RAM memory and provides best Garbage Collection ?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the answer to "what is the best for..." questions is: "It depends"

As you tested, on your hardware and environment setup, without the explicit Collector defined it looks like it automatically selected the Parallel one.

Maybe it only selects it based on the CPU threads available, but in any case it depends much more on how your app behaves. In general: How much memory it will need, what sort of batch memory intensive processes it will run and how often, or if it is doing many concurrent small tasks.

Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/collectors.html) gives you these guidelines and base choices to start with:

> Unless your application has rather strict pause time requirements,
>   first run your application and allow the VM to select a collector. If
>   necessary, adjust the heap size to improve performance. If the
>   performance still does not meet your goals, then use the following
>   guidelines as a starting point for selecting a collector.
>
> - If the application has a small data set (up to approximately 100 MB),
>     then
>
>   select the serial collector with the option -XX:+UseSerialGC.
> - If the application will be run on a single processor and there are no
>     pause time requirements, then let the VM select the collector, or
>     select the serial collector with the option -XX:+UseSerialGC.
> - If (a) peak application performance is the first priority and (b)
>     there are no pause time requirements or pauses of 1 second or longer
>     are acceptable, then let the VM select the collector, or select the
>     parallel collector with -XX:+UseParallelGC.
> - If response time is more important than overall throughput and garbage
>     collection pauses must be kept shorter than approximately 1 second,
>     then select the concurrent collector with -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC or
>     -XX:+UseG1GC.
>
> These guidelines provide only a starting point for selecting a
>   collector because performance is dependent on the size of the heap,
>   the amount of live data maintained by the application, and the number
>   and speed of available processors. Pause times are particularly
>   sensitive to these factors, so the threshold of 1 second mentioned
>   previously is only approximate: the parallel collector will experience
>   pause times longer than 1 second on many data size and hardware
>   combinations; conversely, the concurrent collector may not be able to
>   keep pauses shorter than 1 second on some combinations.
>
> If the recommended collector does not achieve the desired performance,
>   first attempt to adjust the heap and generation sizes to meet the
>   desired goals. If performance is still inadequate, then try a
>   different collector: use the concurrent collector to reduce pause
>   times and use the parallel collector to increase overall throughput on
>   multiprocessor hardware.